# Lanzar WAR en Tomcat 7 no lanza

Tags: java, tomcat, war

Estoy intentando lanzar un war por medio de tomcat 7 ya instale el tomcat y todo bien, el problema es que cuando arranco el server me manda el siguiente mensaje:

> At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable
>    debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but
>    no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve
>   startup time and JSP compilation time.

y en el administrador de tomcat me sale en fail la app

¿Cómo puedo resolver esto?

Comment: que tomcat versión de tomcat estas usando?

Comment: Buenas bienvenido a **StackOverflow** en español por favor antes de preguntar primero ve [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y revisa también [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) edita tu pregunta y mejorarla para tener una respuesta que realmente te ayude.

Comment: Tomcat 7.0.82 el error me sigue saliendo